# Why does my html website look different on my friends pc?

Tags: html, web

MY friend and I made a fake news website for school. Everything looks fine, but when he tries to open it, on the left there is a lot of white space. We think it might be that our desktops have a different size, but we just don´t know how we can change it. HElp would be appriceated.

```
'''<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<title>Werner News</title>
```

```
p {
    font-size: 19px;
}

.WernerNews {
              width: 1650px;
    height: 200px;
}
.CowOrgasm {
              width: 850px;
    height: 400px;
}
 .KyloRen {
              width: 850px;
    height: 400px;
}

 .Lennie {
              width: 850px;
    height: 400px;
}

 .Melzi {
              width: 850px;
    height: 400px;
}
```

```
<table style"width:1500px>
     <colgroup>
        <col span="1" style="width: 50%;">
        <col span="1" style="width: 50%;">
     </colgroup>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
             <td><a href="file:///C:/Users/steph/Downloads/cow_orgasm_news.html"><img class="CowOrgasm" src="file:///C:/Users/steph/Downloads/cow.jpg" alt="Cow Orgasm"></a></td>
             <td><a href="file:///C:/Users/steph/Downloads/kyloren.html"><img class="KyloRen" src="file:///C:/Users/steph/Downloads/kylo.png" alt="Kylo Ren Nudes"></a></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
             <td> <p class="CowText"> Cow´s orgasm is longer than our´s</p></td>
             <td> <p class="KyloRenText">     Kylo Ren seen naked</p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
             <td> <a href="file:///C:/Users/steph/Downloads/news.html"><img class="Lennie" src="file:///C:/Users/steph/Downloads/lennie.jpg" alt="Lennie"></a></td>
             <td><a href="file:///C:/Users/steph/Downloads/melzi.html"><img class="Melzi" src="file:///C:/Users/steph/Downloads/melzi.jpg" alt="Señor Melzita"></a> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
             <td> <p class="LennieText">Tragic desaster about 2 migrant workers in farm</p></td>
             <td><p class="MelziText"><b>Star News: </b>     New best teacher of the world was chosen</p></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

console.log("Buenos días senor Melzi, könnten Sie bitte uns (Louis und Ruben) für diese Idee und das wunderbare Design unserer Fake-News Website" + " eine 1 geben? Vielen Dank im Voraus und Liebe Grüße: Rubinio und Louisa");

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because the files don't exist on your friends pc. `file:///C:/Users/steph/Downloads/cow.jpg` is a specific file path that only exist on your PC.

You can fix this by using relative file paths and sending you friends all the image and .html files. Else these files can't be found and thus you will have a blank space instead of the image.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. We thought of this already and made sure that this is not the problem. He is able to see the pictures, but next to the pictures on the right, there is a lot of white space, that I don´t see when I open it on my pc.

Comment: I see. Then this is probably because his screen is bigger than yours. Try changing `<table style"width:1500px">` in something like `<table style"width:78%">`. If that is not enough convert your the widths in your css to percentages as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because of the different screen sizes try to change your width styles in pixels to percentage

Example:

```
.CowOrgasm {
    width: 60%;
    height: 400px;
}
```

something like above by changing your width until it matches with you requirement

Hope this helps!